# What is the alternative in Harmony OS for Nullable and NonNull annotations?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

There are many arguments in my code which can take the value null. It would be helpful if there is a @Nullable and @NonNull annotation like the ones offered in Android via [Annotation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation).

Is there an alternative available in Harmony OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable** & **org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull** annotations available from jetbrains dependency,

**implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:20.1.0'**

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link and use all the hidden android APIs

https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

From there I ported the annotation interfaces present in the android.annotation package into Harmony OS library that I am making.